# When scrollTop 0 how to scroll up

Tags: javascript, css

I wanna impl android wheel time picker in js

I find this demo: https://demo.mobiscroll.com/jquery/datetime/gregorian-jalali-hijri#

see my gif, the demo scroll view scrollTop always 0, but in my draft code, scrollTop cannot scroll up, so when scrollTop 0, what's mechanism in this demo to scroll up

[image]

Comment: Please post ready-to-use code snippets that we can run and try.

Comment: @BramVanroy my case is I don't know how to make the "scroll up when scrollTop 0" code

Comment: did you try using element.scrollTo(0, 0)?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a user scrolls, it affects an elements scrolling box. windows.scrollTo() will affect the scrolling box of the uppermost containing block. This affects people call it scrolling the window or document.

Answer (score 0):

I find the tmp solution

when scrollTop 0, scroll view event "scroll" doesn't trigger, event "wheel"(mouse wheel scroll up) and "touchmove"(mobile drag to scroll up) still work

following is my code using event "wheel"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--mobile friendly-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes">
  <style>
    .c0 {
      height: 500px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: lightblue;
    }

    .c {
      top: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      height: 300px;
      border: 5px solid black;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .inner {
      background-color: pink;
      margin-top: 0px;
      width: 100%;
      user-select: none;
      height: 1000px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="c0">
  <div class="c">
    <div class="inner">inner</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="module">
  var c = document.querySelector(".c")
  var inner = document.querySelector(".inner")
  var startY
  inner.addEventListener("wheel", (ev) => {
    console.log("wheel")
    inner.style.marginTop = `${inner.offsetTop + ev.deltaY}px`
  })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```